# TeeChart 2017: FastLine AddRealTime auto scales bottom axis despite settings

Tags: activex, teechart

The TeeChart component has a chart series called `IFastLineSeries`.
It allows drawing simple "line type" charts.

Its interface provides a method called `AddRealTime` which is a faster way to add data to the chart than the more generic `AddXY` method.

But `AddRealTime` has a few undocumented side effects:

1. It scrolls the chart to the left when the data almost "overflows" the view (to make room for new data)
2. It can adjust the bottom axis (X-axis range) to fit **all data** when doing so

The first feature is reasonable behavior in a lot of cases: for instance you want to keep showing the most recent process measurements as they are coming in.

However, in my case the automatic scaling for the bottom (X-axis) has been turned off. IMO it shouldn't touch the scaling settings then! But it does.

The second feature is worse: after auto scrolling, the control ensures that all the information is in view. This can slow down the application, because you may have accumulated lots of data in the fast line series which all has to be rendered then... Defeats the "is faster" philosophy behind the method...

I'm okay with the scrolling, but not with the automatic 'zoom out X' action.

Has anyone managed to get `AddRealTime` working without that, or is there no other choice than to fall back to the slower `AddXY` function?
I know I have to adjust the bottom axis myself then to achieve a similar scrolling effect, but at least it would not zoom out unexpectedly.

Remarks:

- Steema software seems to know about this problem, ticket `TA05011024`.
- Their support forums list similar if not the same problems:

  - [How to disable autoscale with fastline series](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6271&start=0&hilit=AddRealTime)
  - [FastLine AddRealTime ignores axis limits](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=2990&highlight=fastline+autoscale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the behaviour you describe in the following way:

You could use Series.AddXY to avoid any of the AddRealtime's automatic behaviour; but you can anyway too, continue to use AddRealtime and modify the behaviour using your own SetMinMax of the Axis to scroll data off to the left, that way maintaining the same number of display points in the chart.

The demo here does just that and addresses your question.
[Github VB TeeChart Add Realtime demo project](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-ActiveX-samples/tree/master/Visual%20Basic/Visual%20Basic%205%20%26%206/FastLine%20AddRealTime)

Comment: I wonder (without having tried the demo project yet) if this solution would zoom and (more importantly) repaint the view once or twice on a scroll-the-data-off event?

In my case there is a considerable amount of data behind the scenes, so even zooming out briefly could trigger a lot of (high CPU consuming) activity in theory.

I recall that ActiveX controls do not always immediately repaint after each property change, so perhaps I'm saved if only the redraw for the final axis settings occurs...

Comment: If you wish to completely control repaint behaviour you can set the Chart's AutoRepaint property to false, use AddXY to add the points and control Axis SetMinMax (optionally), choosing to paint (AutoRepaint=true + Repaint) only when you consider it a best moment to do so.